# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with Exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting a error :-

> "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with Exists"

I'm not sure why. Can someone point me in the right direction? thanks

```
DECLARE @summationhoursint NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @summationhours =
(
    SELECT SUM(hours),
           month,
           firstName
    FROM #temp
    WHERE month = 'january-2017'
          AND firstName = 'Mike'
    GROUP BY month,
             firstName
);
PRINT @summationhours;
```

Comment: You are returning multiple column values in @summationhours. So, select query should return atomic value

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple columns in the SELECT statement. Try this:

```sql
DECLARE @summationhours INT

SET @summationhours= (
  SELECT SUM(hours)
  FROM #temp
  WHERE month = 'january-2017'
  AND firstName = 'Mike'
  )

PRINT @summationhours
```

Answer (score 0):

When your write a sub query and you want to assign a scalar value you can't returns more than one column and more than one row.

You haven't respect both of two constraints because:

- your SELECT fields list has 3 fields: `SUM(hours), month, firstName`
- your subquery has a `GROUP BY` clause, so you have one row for each value combination `month, firstName`.

If you want to assign the total of your hours you can use Serge solution, but if you want to manage the result as you want in your question, you must put the three informations in JOIN with other tables or a similar solution. Please add further details so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can return multiple columns using the following query, the problem is that it is only going to return one row.  Most likely the last row in the result list.  If you need all of the rows from the query I would suggest selecting it into a temp table and working with it as a set.

```
DECLARE @summationhours int ;
DECLARE @Mon int;
DECLARE @FName varchar(100);

SELECT @summationhours = hrs, @Mon = mn, @Fname = firstName from
(
    SELECT SUM(hours) hrs,
           month mn,
           firstName
    FROM #temp
    WHERE month = 'january-2017'
          AND firstName = 'Mike'
    GROUP BY month,
             firstName
) t1;
PRINT @summationhours;
```